# Jquery not working on content page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Is it possible to have a tabbed layout in content page using the JQuery UI ?
I have tabbed layout in master page and when i am trying to add another tabbed layout in content page, JQuery is being ignored.

Or how can I use Jquery UI on content page? Assume that I have button on content page and want to have a UI effect from css file. Is that possible? Can someone give me sample example for the same?

Any help is really appreciated.

here is the master page code for the same where it works fine.

Header section contains the link to Jquery file.

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>

.ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 8em; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {  width: 8em; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { width:6em ; border:none}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border:none; display:block }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;}
    </style>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

```
 <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">Data from Tab1</div>
            <div id="tabs-2">Data from Tab2</div>
            <div id="tabs-3">Data from Tab3</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>


    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //alert("Hi from JS");
        });

        $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
        $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");

    </script>
```

Now here is my content page.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>

        </style>
          <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-4">First Tab</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-5">Second</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-6">Third</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-4">Data from contentPg Tab1</div>
            <div id="tabs-5">Data from contentPg Tab2</div>
            <div id="tabs-6">Data from contentPg Tab3</div>
        </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 //alert("Hi from JS");
             });

             $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
             $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");

    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" style="height: 26px" Text="Button" />
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the output I am getting on a webpage.

[image]

Comment: If JQuery is included in your project then its available to use everywhere, once its loaded. Also Could you post some of what you have tried otherwise you're not really going to get a lot of help from the community as they won;t know what your issue is

Comment: Please have a look at edited code. somehow i am not getting the tabbed layout on the content page and it simply puts data on the display rather than rendering to tabbed layout. I am sure i am missing something here but i am not able to find it.

Comment: I am just trying to create a simple site with one master page and 3-4 content pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you have an id in the master page called "tabs" and that same id is used in the content pages (you have "tabs") there also.  Id's must be unique.

I would suggest switching to using a classes; class="tabs" rather than than the id then your code can switch to using

```
$(".tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
```

and it will apply to all tabs (including those in content pages)